# Log4J SMTPAppender Java

Tags: java, log4j

I want to send a mail notification in a java application via log4j. However the first try with configurated log4j.properties file, worked like charm. But since I want a dynamic subject, which is generated in runtime, I tried the following commands, with no success:

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();

...

public static mail(String msg, String subj) {

   SMTPAppender mailAppend = new SMTPAppender();
   mailAppend.setBufferSize(3);
   mailAppend.setSMTPHost("smtphostname");
   mailAppend.setTo("ex@mple.com");
   mailAppend.setSubject(subj);
   logger.addAppender(mailAppend);
   logger.error(msg);
}
```

output:

```
log4j:ERROR Message object not configured.
```

So did I miss a necessary getter?

Comment: Why not use [JavaMail API](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) ?

Comment: In the application I already use file logging via log4j for trace and so on, so I thaught the easiest way of implementing an extra outgoing mail at some higher prio then trace.

Comment: So, are you trying to send some warnings or error notifications? If so, I'd use a special logger, not the root logger itself. Then I'd modify the appender to change subject, not add a new one over and over again. If the mails have nothing to do with error/logging, then I'd use a different mail lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An SMTPAppender can be configured either using a xml or properties
>   file or manually using the setters. When you use the setters, you need
>   to activate the options by calling the function activateOptions or
>   else you would get the "ERROR Message object not configured" message.
>   This  is to ensure that the options would only become effective when
>   all the related options have been set (e.g. one would not want to have
>   the host setting become effective before the port is set).

FROM : https://community.oracle.com/thread/1758275?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Ty, I tried it and it works as described.
Found another solution which i want to share.

You can simply work with a wild card: so in log4j.properties:

log4j.appender.email.Subject=${mail.subject}

and in java 

System.setProperty("mail.subject", insert_subject_here);
org.apache.log4j.LogManager.resetConfiguration();
PropertyConfigurator.configure("/link/to/log4j.properties");

after that you can simply log an error with updated subject.

Comment: @bhlx Sure, you can add an answer to your own question.